# no indent only on the first line

Tags: formatting

I'm trying to reproduce the following format in text, where I don't have to indent only the first line.

[image]

Using `\noindent` I can format the first row but I don't know how to indent the other.
What can I do?

Comment: Could it be possible that the text you want to format is a bibliography/list of references? If so, please add an example that shows how you currently create such a list of references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `itemize` with an empty label:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[
  label=,
  leftmargin=2em,
  itemindent=-2em,
  nosep,
]

\item Barone G. (2012) Inquinamento atmosferico: il Progetto Regionale sulla Qualità
dell'Aria in Campania; il contributo della Modellistica numerica. Rend.\ Acc.\ Fis.,\ Mat.\ di
Napoli, LXXIX, 11-18.

\item Barone G. (2012) Recente accumulo di metano in atmosfera: origini, influenza sul clima.
Acc.\ Sc.\ Fis.,\ Mat.\ di Napoli. Conversazione del 9/12.

\item Barone G. (2013) Formazione e preservazione di molecole organiche nelle condizioni
estreme del Sistema Solare. Rend.\ Acc.\ Sc.\ Fis.,\ Mat.\ di Napoli, LXXX, 41-50.

\item Barone G. (2014) Nuove informazioni dalle missioni spaziali sulle basi chimiche delle 
origini della vita. Acc.\ Sc.\ Fis.,\ Mat.\ di Napoli. Conversazione del 7/2.

\item Barone G. (2014) L'acqua: le proprietà chimiche e fisiche e interazioni con molecole 
biologiche. Acc.\ Sc.\ Fis.\ Mat. di Napoli. e Acc.\ Pontaniana: XIV Giornata mondiale
dell'acqua, 28/3.

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Please check the consistency: three entries have a comma after “Fis.”, the last one doesn't.

The `showframe` package has only been used for showing the text block boundaries.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may use a description environment. Load the package [enumitem](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) so you can change formatting and style in the easily.

If description does not suit you, you can load the package [hang](https://ctan.org/pkg/hang), and use the `compacthang` environment.

**Example 1**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hang}

\begin{document}

\begin{compacthang}
\item Barone G. (2012)  This is a text without meaning produced to force a linebreak or two. Is it long enough?
\item Barone G. (2012) This is a text without meaning produced to force a linebreak or two. Is it long enough? And here I add more text without meaning, so you can see three lines of text''
\item Barone G. (2012) This is a text without meaning produced to force a linebreak or two. Is it long enough?
\item Barone G. (2012) This is a text without meaning produced to force a linebreak or two. Is it long enough?
\end{compacthang}

\end{document}
```

**Example 2**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[itemsep=0pt, font=\normalfont]
\item[Barone G. (2012)] The option font=normalfont remove the bold letters. This is a text without meaning produced to force a linebreak or two. Is it long enough?
\item[Barone G. (2012)] This is a text without meaning produced to force a linebreak or two. Is it long enough? And here I add more text without meaning, so you can see three lines of text''
\item[Barone G. (2012)] This is a text without meaning produced to force a linebreak or two. Is it long enough?
\item[Barone G. (2012)] This is a text without meaning produced to force a linebreak or two. Is it long enough?
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that if instead of Barone G. (2012) I write something longer then the result is that I go over the borders

Comment: @malloc By the way, it was not meant that you should put a whole sentence inside the description element. Based on your example, my understonding was  that your were searching for something to typeset a bibliography style list.